# How to assign non-string dynamic attributes to a nested component in Svelte?

Tags: javascript, typescript, svelte

For a Svelte component with dynamic attributes which are not strings (i.e. a number and array), for example `MySimpleComponent.svelte`:

```html
<script lang="ts">
    export let index : number;
    export let paragraphs: string[];
</script>

<h3> { index } </h3>
{#each paragraphs as paragraph, i}
    <p> { paragraph } </p>  
{/each}
```

What is the correct syntax to place that component in a different component, and specify those attributes inline? I am trying this, but it doesn't work:

```html
<script lang="ts">
    import MySimpleComponent from './MySimpleComponent.svelte';
</script>

<MySimpleComponent
    index = { 1 },
    paragraphs = {[
        'Nisi ab nesciunt sapiente. Et nostrum quo qui quia non.',
        'Aut vel quia vel ducimus eius perferendis.' 
    ]},
/>
```

The error is TS 2322: `Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'` (or `to type string[]`). I assume because the `{ }` syntax is implicitly expecting a string inside, meaning `{ 1 }` is really `'1'`, not `1`.

What is the correct way to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem should be commas, props are separated only by whitespace:

```html
<MySimpleComponent
    index={1}
    paragraphs={[
        'Nisi ab nesciunt sapiente. Et nostrum quo qui quia non.',
        'Aut vel quia vel ducimus eius perferendis.' 
    ]} />
```

(Whitespace in/around the braces and next to the `=` should *not* matter.)

Curly braces pass values verbatim without any conversion. To pass strings one would use quotes around the values with other text or invoke `.toString()` manually (e.g. `index="1"`).

Note that if a property only contains a `{...}` expression it will *not* be converted to a string but again passed verbatim (see [this issue](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/7925) for examples).

Comment: Ah, very simple solution, thank you. Because of the mix and match of JS and HTML in some Svelte syntax, got confused between JSON notation and HTML notation. I guess it makes sense that a component's properties are HTML-like.